# Plural of expertise when comparing two people

Tags: grammatical-number

When referring to two people with different areas of expertise, should "expertise" be made plural? The only reference I found (https://preply.com/en/question/plural-of-expertise) lacks citations and specificity on which "specific contexts" warrant the plural "expertises".

Edit (to avoid the "opinion-based" designation): which of these sentences is more common in standard English writing?

> "Given our divergent expertise in science and literature but our
> shared interest in sports..."

> "Given our divergent expertises in science and literature but our
> shared interest in sports..."

Thanks!

Comment: I think most writers would try to avoid *expertises*. There are multiple ways to avoid it.

Comment: ... eg 'levels of expertise'.

Comment: 'Areas of expertise'.

Comment: Makes sense. I'm going to use "divergent areas of expertise". Thanks. Edit: @YosefBaskin, great minds think alike!

Comment: This is one of those questions where it is reasonable to expect basic dictionary research to be presented (eg CD, Collins and OLD only recognise noncount singular-form usage), though the best answer will require rather more. Sadly, that is likely to be opinion.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "levels of expertise" would be more appropriate when comparing people in the same area. E.g. a beginning programmer and an experienced programmer have different levels of expertise in programming.

Comment: There are *many* written instances of the plural usage [*their **expertises.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22their+expertises%22) But as [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=their+expertises%2Ctheir+areas+of+expertise&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) clearly shows, that ("ugly", to me) usage is completely dwarfed by the more elegantly pluralised *their **areas** of expertise*

Comment: @Barmar Yes; probably more likely given 'but our shared interest in sports' ... but then again, surely everyone has a certain level of expertise in such areas as science and literature, however rudimentary.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But I think the intent is to distinguish expertise in science versus literature -- each has expertise in one of them.

Comment: "Given our different aptitudes, yours in science and mine in literature, ....' 'Aptitude' is certainly countified.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I don't have enough rep to vote to reopen. But I would accept your graph (or something like this: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=our+expertises%2Cour+areas+of+expertise&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) as the answer if the question were re-opened.

Comment: @Josh: If the question had been asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) I might have posted the chart as an Answer, but on ELU I think it's just a matter of opinion whether you're prepared to use the somewhat ungainly plural (most native speakers would probably just rephrase to avoid having to think too much about it! :)

Comment: I may have misunderstood, but in the "What topics can I ask about here?" (https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section "Questions on the following topics are welcomed here", the very first entry is "Word choice and usage". Does my question not fall under this category?